# Collection of stats in oracle

Tags: oracle, statistics, database-performance

Collecting Stats in oracle- How Performance gets improved?

When doing collect stats on fields/indexes , system collects the information like: total row counts of the table, how many distinct values are there in the column, how many rows per value, is the column indexed, if so unique or non unique etc

The above information are known as statistics.

1.How Performance gets improved?

2.How does the Parsing Engine/Cost Based Optimizer(CBO) use the statistics for the better performance of a query?

3.Why do i need to collect stats on the indexed columns , despite the fact
using indexed columns in where clause/joins itself will give better performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The above information are known as statistics. so How Performance gets improved?

Because the more and accurate information will let the **optimizer** decide for a better **execution plan**.

For example,

When you try to reach your destination for the first time, you gather information about the routes, directions, landmark etc. Once you reach your destination, you have all the information gathered, and the next time  you would reach your destination using the shortest path or the best way to reach in least time.

Comment: Oh wow better example,thank you...Can you also explain in detail about above 3 question in perspective of oracle

Comment: 1.Where are these statistics stored?                                                                                     2.where does the following information are stored?
a)how many rows per value,
b)is the column indexed, if so unique or non unique etc

Comment: @srinathjikyadari It could be explained, but not as an answer on Stack Overflow as it is too broad. I am afraid, if you include these points then the question might be closed as too-broad. Have a look at this white paper http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bi-datawarehousing/twp-statistics-concepts-12c-1963871.pdf

Comment: Also, go through the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how the site works. How does the voting works, and how to accept an answer. All the best!

Comment: okay,i will go through it ...thank you for your support